# Hide and Show specific elements within a ul in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

Based on some user inputs , I wish to display several options to the user(The options could be single or multiple options from option-1 to option-5 or it could be only error)

My HTML code is :

```
<input id="optiondisplay" value="Options" readonly/>
<ul id="option-list">
    <li id="option-1">Option 1</li>
    <li id="option-2">Option 2</li>
    <li id="option-3">Option 3</li>
    <li id="option-4">Option 4</li>
    <li id="option-5">Option 5</li>
    <li id="option-error"><b>Error: Invalid input.</b></li>
</ul>
```

Now, I am using below Jquery code to display options:

```
case (some input)
                $('#optiondisplay').show();
                $('#option-error').hide();
                $('#option-1').hide();
                $('#option-2').hide();
                $('#option-3').hide();
                $('#option-4').show();
                $('#option-5').show();
                break;
```

However, as you all can see here, there is a lot of rewriting of code for each user inputs( I have to show some elements and also hide others) . 
Is there any other way I can achieve this?
Thanks.

**EDITED: Input from User** :

```
<input type="text" id="from-datepicker"/>
<input type="text" id="to-datepicker"/>
```

Based on the diffrence between the from and to dates, I show the above options.

Comment: What are you collecting the user input from, text inputs, select element?

Comment: Yes, certainly there will be a way; however, we need more information. Maybe start a jsfiddle. Also, what is an example of what you want to show/hide based on selection?

Comment: why not use multiple selectors ? like ("#opt1,#opt2,#opt3").hide().

Comment: Helps to know more about the `some input` and what it's source is.  Also consider `$('#option-list').children().hide()` then all you need in each case is to account for `show()`. Other array approaches depending on how UI works

Comment: Hi all, I have added the user input parameters

Comment: Still vague what implication is of difference between dates and impact on what gets displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st:** you can use something like

```
$('#option-1 ,#option-2 , #option-3').hide();
$('#option-4 , #option-5').show();
```

**2nd:** you can use a simple function to show and hide the options as you need

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // run function with array of options you need to show
  // make this array as you like [0,2] or [3,5] up to you 
  // the index starts from 0
  OptionsShowHide([0,3])
});


// function to show what li we need and hide others
function OptionsShowHide(arr){
  $('li[id^="option-"]').each(function(i){
    if($.inArray( i , arr) > -1){
      $(this).show();
    }else{
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="optiondisplay" value="Options" readonly/>
<ul id="option-list">
    <li id="option-1">Option 1</li>
    <li id="option-2">Option 2</li>
    <li id="option-3">Option 3</li>
    <li id="option-4">Option 4</li>
    <li id="option-5">Option 5</li>
    <li id="option-error"><b>Error: Invalid input.</b></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamaed. I tried the 1st option and worked as expected. However, I see there's some lag before the new output is to be displayed.
Is there any work around for that?

Comment: @nerd In normal It shouldn't be any lag .try to use show(0)  and hide(0)   ..  0 mean time .. if its not working so the lag not from show and hide maybe something else in your code